# Possible to find an explanation of Windows updates in "digest" format?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates

Is it possible to see an explanation of individual Windows 7 updates without having to manually google each one by one (e.g., "KB3021917")?

I wish there were more detailed descriptions in the Windows Update panel for each, rather than "This is for generic something something issue."

Comment: I've been looking for what you describe for a long time, in particular to find update descendants (other updates that a given update has been rolled into or redistributed with). Never really found anything though. I end up having to just click each link...

Comment: @FrankThomas: [This script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/0dbfc125-b855-4058-87ec-930268f03285) could be a starting point. Haven't looked at it in detail, though.

Comment: This question on ServerFault also seems related: http://serverfault.com/q/704553/95758

Answer (score 2):

User [krlmlr](https://superuser.com/users/99136/krlmlr) pointed me to this question after I asked a similar question on Serverfault on how to change the update descriptions on a WSUS server (Windows Server Update Services). WSUS is used in enterprise environments to manage updates and patches for all workstations in one place.

[Serverfault: Can I change the update descriptions in WSUS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/704553/can-i-change-the-update-descriptions-in-wsus/)

Meanwhile I solved my problem by creating a little tool, that updates the WSUS  database with the official update descriptions from Microsoft's KB articles. WSUS is using an internal database to store all of its information, including the (generic) update descriptions.

I posted the download link as an [answer to my question linked above](https://serverfault.com/a/704872/298476).

My post may not answer your question in all details, but I thought it may be helpful for some people. I uploaded the tool to Github, so you may download and use the source code to create a similar one for the Windows 7 Update view.

[image: Sample screenshot of the update tool]

Comment: I do think that this answers the question here very well, provided that it also works when getting updates directly from Microsoft. Do you want to link directly to your answer, or perhaps better add a brief description of the tool?

Comment: @krlmlr I just added a link to my answer, the program's screenshot and extended the description about technial background and functionality of the tool. If you think I can improve my post further, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but try the following:

Open your Windows Updates,

Either check at `Check for updates` or `View update history`, depending if you want to know for new updates or the ones that were already installed.

## Check for updates

At the screen where you can select the updates to install, click the update you want to check, then at the right it says what the update is about. A link with More information directly brings you to the assigned KB on microsoft's website.

## View update history

The View update history lists all updates that were previously installed. Click any update, right-click and choose View details (or doubleclick that specific update)
The same update information can be found here with an additional More information link that points to the website of MS.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the OP's question. The point was, as I understand, to avoid having to click the "More information" link in the first place.

Comment: @krlmlr, I am not so sure. The description of the post is somewhat vague in that regard. The post itself does ask for what I answered, while the title mentioned digest. Given that I don't think a digest is possible, I chosen to answer the post itself, and by that definition I think my post is answering the question.

Comment: OP asked: "without having to manually google each one by one". Your answer substitutes this by "still have to manually click a link for each update, one by one". This is just slightly better than manually searching for the updates -- would you mind adding a more visible disclaimer to your answer?

Comment: @krlmlr agreed, but to my knowledge there is no better solution. Feel free to post the solution yourself. Thats what this site is all about.

Comment: I appreciate your input LPChip, but @krlmlr is correct -- I'm looking for something other than Windows' present implementation, which is klugey and doesn't provide any useful information for each update's description paragraph. Ideally, a utility would would scrape the info from each KB's respective webpage, which explains what the update is for and does. I've been hoping for a third-party utility, and am surprised none seem to exist. I suppose I should roll up my sleeves and make this myself. And shall.

Comment: @Coldblackice: I'd love to have that, too :-) Ping me here or on GitHub if there's any news.

Comment: @Coldblackice Unfortunately SuperUser is not a place for asking software recommendations. The question you have simply is not possible with what's available, so my answer seems to be the correct one, even if it doesn't satisfy your needs. I'm sorry but this is the best SuperUser can offer you.

Comment: @LPChip Understood, and makes sense. As I'm planning to build a solution to this myself, I'll revise the question so it's more in line with protocol. I suppose a better fit is asking if it's possible to get the "More information" without having to click the external links, obtaining the information through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following workaround, works for me in Windows 8.1:

- In the list of updates, select all updates you want to get the details for (multi-select)
- Right-click, choose "Copy details"
- The clipboard now contains the usual meaningless text ("Install this update to resolve issues in Windows."), **plus** the URLs that link to the real thing, for **all** updates you have selected.

From there, you simply need to open all relevant URLs, a Chrome extension ("Copy All URLs" by Vincent Paré) did the job for me after I turned on "Intelligent paste" in the options.